# How to get back name of the enum element?

Tags: python, enums

I have an enum defined like this:

```
def enum(**enums):
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

Status = enum(
       STATUS_OK=0,
       STATUS_ERR_NULL_POINTER=1, 
       STATUS_ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER=2)
```

I have a function that returns status as `Status` enum. 
How can I get the name of the enum value, and not just value?

```
>>> cur_status = get_Status()
>>> print(cur_status)
1
```

I would like to get `STATUS_ERR_NULL_POINTER`, instead of `1`

Comment: **Note**: if Python standard library's `enum.Enum` is used, refer to this question → [How to convert int to Enum in python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951641/how-to-convert-int-to-enum-in-python)

Answer (score 95):

You'd have to loop through the class attributes to find the matching name:

```
name = next(name for name, value in vars(Status).items() if value == 1)
```

The generator expression loops over the attributes and their values (taken from the dictionary produced by the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars)) then returns the first one that matches the value `1`.

Enumerations are better modelled by the [`enum` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), available in Python 3.4 or as a [backport for earlier versions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34):

```
from enum import Enum

class Status(Enum):
    STATUS_OK = 0
    STATUS_ERR_NULL_POINTER = 1 
    STATUS_ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 2
```

giving you access to the name and value:

```
name = Status(1).name  # gives 'STATUS_ERR_NULL_POINTER'
value = Status.STATUS_ERR_NULL_POINTER.value  # gives 1
```

Comment: And how about Status(4)? How can you make an undefined value return a default or None instead of throwing an exception?

Answer (score 66):

2021 update:
These answers are out of date. Using Python's standard Enum class,

```
cur_status.name
```

will return the name. (STATUS_ERR_NULL_POINTER)

To look up the enum knowing the name:

```
s = Status['STATUS_ERR_NULL_POINTER']
```

Comment: The question is not about Python's `Enum`, but one the OP created.

Comment: OP should be using Python's enum :)

Comment: This answer does not address the OP's original question, where only the value (`1`) is given instead of the enumeration object, so `(1).name` is invalid. (although it appears useful to some other people).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure which python version it was introduced, but the hidden attribute `_value2member_map_` gives you what you want.

```
class Status(Enum):
    STATUS_OK=0
    STATUS_ERR_NULL_POINTER=1
    STATUS_ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER=2

str(Status._value2member_map_[1])
```

Out:

```
'Status.STATUS_ERR_NULL_POINTER'
```

Comment: You could simply use `Status(1).name`

Comment: Oh, that is much simpler!

Comment: The question is not about Python's `Enum`, but one the OP created.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to loop through the Enum class but just access _member_map_.

```
>>> Status._member_map_['STATUS_OK']
<Status.STATUS_OK: 0>
```

Comment: The question was to find an enum by value (in your example `0`)

Comment: This is useful but backwards :)

Comment: The question is not about Python's `Enum`, but one the OP created.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, most of the methods above did not work for me.  All methods return the Enum type as an integer.  I'm working with Python 3.7.

In my solution, I defined class function to handle this.  It's not purely pythonic, but worked well enough for my case.

```
from enum import Enum
    
class Status(Enum):
    STATUS_OK = 0
    STATUS_ERR_NULL_POINTER = 1 
    STATUS_ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 2
    
    @classmethod
    def name(cls,val):
        return { v:k for k,v in dict(vars(cls)).items() if isinstance(v,int)}.get(val,None)

# test it
stat = Status.STATUS_OK
print(Status.name(stat))
```

Prints: `'STATUS_OK'`

It may seem obvious that we asked for the status after giving it the status, but in my case, this is set programmatically elsewhere