# Python Flask RestPlus Enum Type

Tags: python, flask, enums, flask-restplus

Am using `python 3.4.` I have created an `enum` type as shown below:

```
import enum
class EnumGender(enum.Enum):
    blank = ' '
    female = 'Female'
    male = 'Male'
    other = 'Other'
```

my question is how do i assign it to flask-restplus field as the only examples i can see are:

`fields.String(description='The object type', enum=['A', 'B'])`

Comment: What's your intent here? Are you looking to use the enum field for validation, just for added typing or some other reason?

Comment: For those in need of enums, consider choices=...
https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/124

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can assign the member names to it:

```
fields.String(description='The object type', enum=EnumGender._member_names_)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a enum.IntEnum with fields.Integer?

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#iteration) tell me that there is no `Enum._member_names_` but there is `Enum.__members__` which is a view. So you'll have to do `fields.String(description='The object type', enum=EnumGender.__members__.items())`. A little verbose.

Comment: For me __members__items() throws unserializable error, although _member_names_ is protected but it works.

Answer (score 4):

I have opted for this approach:

```
fields.String(attribute=lambda x: str(EnumGender(x.FieldContainingEnum).name))
```

(Source: [How to get back name of the enum element in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880323/how-to-get-back-name-of-the-enum-element-in-python))

Answer (score 1):

in my case having enum like this:

```
from enum import Enum


class SubscriptionEvent(Enum):
    on_success = "ON_SUCCESS"
    on_error = "ON_ERROR"
```

I needed definition in marshal like this:

```
subscription_action_serializer = api.model('SubscriptionAction', {
    'event': fields.String(enum=[x.value for x in SubscriptionEvent], attribute='event.value'),
})
```

I needed just accept and present as valid enum values `"ON_SUCCESS", "ON_SUCCESS"`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, Python 3.7.3 (circa Nov 2019):

```
fields.String(description="The object type",
              enum=[x.name for x in EnumGender])
```